# I cant handle promise rejections

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, socket.io, promise, unhandled-exception

I have a service that analyses websites, compresses their sources like CSS Documents, Images etc. I have 2 functions, one is Socket.IO `socket.on()` method with async callback function. Another is main function for service.

```
socket.on('run', async options => {
    debug(`${options.target} Adresine Bir Kullanıcı İstek Yaptı!`);
    let user = null;
    console.log(options);
    if(options.token) {
        user = await User.findById(jwt.verify(options.token, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))._id);
        options.userId = user._id.toString();
    } else if(options.visitor) {
        user = await Visitor.findById(options.visitor._id);
        if(user.report) {
            return socket.emit('error', new Error('You have exceeded your report limit'));
        } else {
            options.userId = user._id.toString();
        }
    }
    if(options.userId) {
        let userType = await UserType.find({ name: user.type });
        if(userType.length > 0 && ((user.type == 'Visitor' && user.report == undefined) || (user.reports.length < userType[0].rights.reportsLimit.limit || userType[0].rights.reportsLimit.unlimited))) {
            options.rights = userType[0].rights;
            let { error, data } = await wrapper(runService(options.target, options, socket));
            if(error) {
                console.log('Here', error);
                return socket.emit('error', error);
            }
        .
        .
        .
        }
    .
    .
    .
    }
});
```

In the above function,

```
let { error, data } = await wrapper(runService(options.target, options, socket));
if(error) {
    console.log('Here', error);
    return socket.emit('error', error);
}
```

This part is important, because I call my main async service function `runService` with my async function wrapper function that is named `wrapper`. The wrapper function is this;

```
const wrapper = promise => (
    promise
        .then(data => ({ data, error: null }))
        .catch(error => ({ error, data: null }))
);
```

In my main async service function, I only throw an error;

```
async function runService(target, options, socket) {
     throw new Error('any error');
}
```

But the expected output is much different from actual output. Here is the output of this code;

```
Here Error: any error
    at startService (C:\Projeler\OpDetect\Background-Service\lib\app.js:404:11)
    at Socket.socket.on (C:\Projeler\OpDetect\Background-Service\app.js:73:57)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:16600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: any error
    at startService (C:\Projeler\OpDetect\Background-Service\lib\app.js:404:11)
    at Socket.socket.on (C:\Projeler\OpDetect\Background-Service\app.js:73:57)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:16600) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.
 This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:16600) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
```

the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

My expectation about the output is, like this;

```
Here Error: any error
    at startService (C:\Projeler\OpDetect\Background-Service\lib\app.js:404:11)
    at Socket.socket.on (C:\Projeler\OpDetect\Background-Service\app.js:73:57)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Because I already handled the promise rejection with my wrapper function and catched the rejection, Why is 2 more `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` errors on rejection?

Also, the line,

```
return socket.emit('error', error);
```

is not calling for no reason. It should have been called when the `if` statement truthy. Why is not this `socket.emit` function called?

Comment: this is very weird, since this don't throw unhanded exception in console: `await new Promise((r, e) => e('x')).catch(x => ({x}))`

Comment: Same as this `await wrapper((async function() { throw new Error('x'); })())` it don't throw exception only return `{error: new Error('x')}`, maybe problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Yea, I find the problem. socket.emit('error', params) is an API Method that is built-in to socket.io. When it called, it throws error. I did not know it is special event listener, so I renamed event name 'error' to 'throw-error' and its done :)

Answer (score 1):

As best practice use `try {} catch(){}` with async/await.

For ex.

```
userUtils.signUp = async (userName) => {
try {
    const callFunction = await userUtils.checkExistancy(userName);

    if (!callFunction.isExist) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
 }

};
```

in your case it will be like

```
socket.on('run', async options => {
try {
    user = await User.findById(jwt.verify(options.token, config.get('jwtPrivateKey'))._id);
    options.userId = user._id.toString();
    return true;
} catch (err) {
    throw err;
}});
```

Comment: Where should I put my code in a try/catch statement? Exactly, which function?

Comment: I find the problem. socket.emit('error', params) is an API Method that is built-in to socket.io. When it called, it throws error. I did not know it is special event listener, so I renamed event name 'error' to 'throw-error' and its done :)